# How to Convert English to Spanish using php

Tags: php

We developed an App in Android and Iphone which support language in English.Now we plan to show the app content in Spanish also.What is the best approach to do this.

How we convert the English to Spanish using PHP to show data in Spanish also

Comment: ... What does PHP have to do with a mobile app?

Comment: the content in mobile app is from php web service

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop a webapp system which will be easy to localize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713320/how-to-develop-a-webapp-system-which-will-be-easy-to-localize)

Comment: Then the mobile app itself is irrelevant; only the PHP matters.

Answer (score 1):

Use language files for English and Spanish and whatever you need. and by the usage of those and an XML file you can implement this.

Please take a look here, this may help you [How to Make Your Website Support for Multi Language with PHPMaker
8.0.3](http://www.ilovephpmaker.com/tips-and-trick/how-to-make-your-website-support-for-multi-language-with-phpmaker-8-0-3/)

Answer (score 0):

Internationalization is what you are looking for. It is a fairly simple process(provided you are going to work with languages that are not encoding-specific). Data which changes with locale is isolated into seperate files which are locale-specific. Then when the locale of the user is identified, the specific locale file is loaded and the word from that locale is substituted in the placeholder. Wherever you are going to introduce this, I am sure Google can guide to an extensive tutorial.